# IDA PRO _data keeps getting misaligned lost bytes while scrolling down Can't find references (hint: redo analisys)

Tags: ida

[image]

The code of the functions is still valid but now the `_data` segment keeps losing 6 bytes everytime I fix it by pressing `G` going to `42A000` fixing what it undoes then I scroll down a bit and scroll back up and I'll notice `42A000` is completely gone when I go into Hex View I'll notice it doesn't show the 6 bytes.

Also going bit lower I noticed my string started to get lost too when I started I had a bunch more strings then I have now the first string is cut half way with a bunch of fake assembly code.

My strings keep disappearing one by one each time I work on re-factoring it.

Is there a way to re-position / move this string / constants information or maybe keep it blocked from being de-synced.

Whats the cause of it? I checked all the functions I've edited they all start and end with the same addresses as a fresh original none re-factored load of the same file.

Here's a few pictures of the problems.

There are the errors in the output that get generated as I scroll down.

[image: 0]

This is how it looks good when I use `G` + `42A000`

[image: 1]

This is what happens when I scroll a full screen view away from `42A000` then come back 6 bytes are lost. I'd like to add that `align 800` I've added it only had `align 1000` but that's because there was a bunch of zero bytes there so I guess the `align` just hides em for now I'll use them if I need to later.

[image: 2]

Here is the Hex-View after a screw up, you can see the first 6 are not in use.

[image: 3]

Here you can see the first String is `Player leaving game %s',0AH, 0` which isn't even on the strings of the Hex-View above that's how much strings are lost so far.

[image: 4]

When you scroll down far enough then scroll back up it even makes more of a mess.

[image: 5]

Any advise what I should do? I'll probably start from a fresh revision of the exe and slowly start fixing things up and looking at the bottom each time to see if anything messes up. Or is there a way to find out what screwed it up? or maybe a way to prevent further screws up in the future? to be honest I recall it screwed up on a fresh project as well just the first time it messed up it just kept undoing my changes with Keys `A`'s and `O`'s and `D`'s

Answer (score 1):

"redo analisys"?  Why is a commercial product misspelling "analysis"?

I would suspect hardware or serious software problems.  Do you have unexpected computer crashes?  faulty memory?  corrupted disc structure?

If none of those, and in the absence of any better advice I would reinstall IDA, check your hard drives, make sure you have sufficient RAM that is correctly configured in BIOS and check your IDA against a different project.

Comment: Well I don't think anything is wrong with IDA PRO really it's just it's really risky with no undo's If you get a Please confirm The new variable size is bigger than the old one. You should get scared haha. I am almost done renaming from the screwed up project back to a fresh version. Might work better.